# My own arraylist

Tags: java, methods, insert, arraylist

I need to do my own arraylist class. I am trying to write insert method, I am facing an issue adding object to index 0 if there is an already existing object in this index. It works for other indices, but not for 0. Any help would be appreciated?

```
public void insert(int index, Object object) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {

    if(index < 0) {
        System.out.println("Niepoprawny index!");
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    if(index > array.length - 1 || array[index] != null) {
        // zwiększenie rozmiaru tablicy
        // jeśli jest zbyta mała lub na danym miejscu istnieje jakiś obiekt
        Object[] temp = new Object[array.length + index];
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, temp, 0, array.length);
        array = temp;
    }

    // przesunięcie o 1 w prawo wszystkich elementów
    System.arraycopy(array, index - 1, array, index, array.length - index);
    array[index] = object;
    size++;
}
```

Comment: `System.arraycopy(array, index - 1, array, index, array.length - index);` What will this line be doing when `index` is `0`?

Answer (score 5):

1. The size of `temp` is wrong. Since you're adding a single element, it should be `array.length + 1`.
2. The indices in the second `arraycopy` are wrong.
3. I don't quite get the `array[index] != null` check.

Finally, the entire body of the `if` can be replaced with a single call to [`Arrays.copyOfRange()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29).

Comment: If i have array.length + 1 it doesn't work. I need to check array[index] != null, because if i don't do this size of array don't increase when i will try to add new object on busy "index". Can you tell me more about the indices in the second arraycopy? What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

With this line, you try to insert data at index -1:

```
System.arraycopy(array, index - 1, array, index, array.length - index);
```

Comment: I notice this, but it still does not work if i have:
    
    if(index == 0) System.arraycopy(array, 0, array, 1, 1);
    else System.arraycopy(array, index - 1, array, index, array.length - index);
    array[index] = object;
    size++;

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyArrayList<E> {
    private int listSize = 0; // arraySize
    private int initialArraySize = 1;//initial size
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private E[] data = (E[]) new Object[initialArraySize];//initialize array


    /**
     * auto increase array upon every added element
     * @return 
     */
    private  void IncreaseArraySize() {
        //increase the size of the array by one element when element is added
        data = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length+1);
        }

    /**
     * add elements to myArrayList
     */

    public void add(E toBeAdded) {
        //add to array then change the array size by one element
        int i= data.length;
        if(listSize == data.length){
            IncreaseArraySize();
        }
        data[listSize] = toBeAdded;
        listSize++;
    }   

    /**
     * 
     * @param remove item from MyarrayList
     * 
     */
    public void remove(E ItemToRemove) {
        //remove the element you and then shrinks the array to new size after removal
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
            if (data[i]==ItemToRemove) {
                for (int j = i; j < data.length-1; j++) {
                    data[j] = data[j + 1];
                }
            }
        }
        listSize--;
    }

    /**
     * to check if list contains the item
     */
    public boolean contains(E toCheck) {
        //iterate all elements of array while comparing element you want to the one in the index
        boolean b = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i]==toCheck) {
                b = true;
            }
        }
        return b;
    }
/**
 * checks if list is empty
 */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        //return false if list is not empty else true if if it is
        boolean b = false;
        if ((data.length == 1) && (data[0] == null)) {
            b = true;
        }
        return b;
    }

    /**
     * pass index you want to check contents
     */
    public E get(int index) {
        //make sure the index is not empty and not out of the array
        if (index < data.length && null != data[index]) {
            E ElementPos = data[index];
            return  ElementPos;
        } else if (index < 0 || index > data.length) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * get the size of array
     */
    public int size() {
        return listSize;    

    }
}
```